# Xcode 9 project templates folders bug

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

I have a Xcode project template that works well in Xcode 8.3.1, but in Xcode 9 my groups duplicates in project as folders, and location in File inspector of each group is missing (Xcode writes "Containing directory") and groups with several files duplicated several times.

[image]

Here is the repository with [source of templates](https://github.com/surfstudio/Xcode-Project-Templates).

Let me know how to fix this bug please.